# Where can I find Cardano Dapp code and demo examples?

Tags: decentralized-applications

I am checking Cardano documentation to develop Cardano POC for my Dapp, found some good examples to create contracts using online application i.e. Plutus (https://playground.plutus.iohkdev.io/).

However, there are no examples given to create end-to-end applications like those provided in Ethereum documentation i.e. Ethereum has provided web3 applications examples to create Dapps using Web3 / React/ Solidity contracts connecting the dapp to Ethereum testnet/mainnet - many examples are available on internet and ethereum documentation website for reference.

I have not found demo examples of how Dapps can be built using Cardano.

Please can someone share some code and demo examples or links to them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a number of dApps demo examples in the [Plutus Pioneer Program](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-pioneer-program/tree/main/code) repository.

Answer (score 2):

I have recently finished transcribing lecture 6 from the Plutus Pioneer Program which runs through the process of creating a swap dApp that uses an oracle for exchange rate data. It consists of two clients - one for the oracle provider, and one for participants who want to offer swaps and accept swaps. [The week 6 lecture can be seen here](https://plutus-pioneer-program.readthedocs.io/en/latest/week6.html).

Comment: Well done. Your explanations are spot on for a topic most people are largely in the dark about.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a lot of examples in the official Plutus repository https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus/tree/master/plutus-use-cases/src/Plutus/Contracts